# Spring Native: No classes have been predefined during the image build to load from bytecodes at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I have a spring boot application in which I have added the configurations for the [spring native](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html). I am successfully able to build the native image using the `mvn clean -Pnative spring-boot:build-image`. However when I start the containerized native image I am getting the below error. I am using Spring Boot 3.1.0 and Java 17. Is there any configurations that I need to add while building the native image? How can I fix the issue?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'myConfigRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.resolveArgument(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:315) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.resolveArguments(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:258) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.get(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:198) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.InstanceSupplier$1.get(InstanceSupplier.java:83) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.obtainInstanceFromSupplier(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:947) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.RegisteredBean.resolveAutowiredArgument(RegisteredBean.java:219) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.resolveArgument(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:312) ~[na:na]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xeroConfigRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1682) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.RegisteredBean.resolveAutowiredArgument(RegisteredBean.java:219) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.resolveArgument(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:312) ~[na:na]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Failed to asynchronously initialize native EntityManagerFactory: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: No classes have been predefined during the image build to load from bytecodes at runtime.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365) ~[na:na]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to asynchronously initialize native EntityManagerFactory: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: No classes have been predefined during the image build to load from bytecodes at runtime.
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.getNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:575) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:519) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:733) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy170.getMetamodel(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:na]
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1845) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:na]
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:na]
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:na]
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:na]
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:na]
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.getMetamodels(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:94) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:68) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:44) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:142) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.0.9]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: No classes have been predefined during the image build to load from bytecodes at runtime.
    at com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError.unsupportedFeature(VMError.java:89) ~[na:na]
    at com.oracle.svm.core.hub.PredefinedClassesSupport.throwNoBytecodeClasses(PredefinedClassesSupport.java:76) ~[na:na]
    at com.oracle.svm.core.hub.PredefinedClassesSupport.loadClass(PredefinedClassesSupport.java:130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:294) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:na]
    at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher$DynamicClassLoader.invoker(JavaDispatcher.java:1383) ~[na:na]
    at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher$InvokerCreationAction.run(JavaDispatcher.java:459) ~[na:na]
    at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher$InvokerCreationAction.run(JavaDispatcher.java:452) ~[na:na]
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(AccessController.java:168) ~[na:na]
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318) ~[na:na]
    at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher.doPrivileged(JavaDispatcher.java) ~[na:na]
    at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher.<clinit>(JavaDispatcher.java:87) ~[na:na]
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$ForLoadedType.<clinit>(TypeDescription.java:8659) ~[na:na]
    at net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.isFinalizer(ElementMatchers.java:1624) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState$ProxyDefinitionHelpers.<init>(ByteBuddyState.java:296) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.<clinit>(ByteBuddyState.java:71) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.BytecodeProviderImpl.<init>(BytecodeProviderImpl.java:123) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.BytecodeProviderImpl.<init>(BytecodeProviderImpl.java:115) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.BytecodeProviderInitiator.buildBytecodeProvider(BytecodeProviderInitiator.java:59) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.BytecodeProviderInitiator.buildDefaultBytecodeProvider(BytecodeProviderInitiator.java:46) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.enhance.EnhancingClassTransformerImpl.<init>(EnhancingClassTransformerImpl.java:34) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor.pushClassTransformer(PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor.java:113) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:340) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:190) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:na]
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:na]
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:na]
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:na]
    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:775) ~[com.abc.xyz.Application:na]
    at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:203) ~[na:na]
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myapp</name>
    <description>My Application</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <springdoc-openapi-ui.version>1.6.13</springdoc-openapi-ui.version>
        <problem.version>0.26.0</problem.version>
        <org.json.version>20220320</org.json.version>
        <apache.commons.lang3.version>3.12.0</apache.commons.lang3.version>
        <checkstyle-plugin.version>3.2.0</checkstyle-plugin.version>
        <checkstyle.version>10.5.0</checkstyle.version>
        <spotbugs-plugin.version>4.7.3.4</spotbugs-plugin.version>
        <spotbugs-annotations.version>4.7.3</spotbugs-annotations.version>
        <pmd-plugin.version>3.21.0</pmd-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>${org.json.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.commons.lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>problem-spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${problem.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-problem</artifactId>
            <version>${problem.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spotbugs-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${spotbugs-annotations.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <docker>
                        <publishRegistry>
                            <username>${docker.publishRegistry.username}</username>
                            <password>${docker.publishRegistry.password}</password>
                        </publishRegistry>
                    </docker>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.26</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${checkstyle-plugin.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                        <version>${checkstyle.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>checkstyle</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <excludes>**/module-info.java,**/target/**/*,**/protocols/**/*</excludes>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                    <violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>
                    <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${pmd-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                            <goal>cpd-check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <printFailingErrors>true</printFailingErrors>
                    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/domain/**/**.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spotbugs-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <excludeFilterFile>spotbugs-ignore.xml</excludeFilterFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties** file

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer=allow
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=lazy
#logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
#logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
#spring.jpa.show-sql=true

logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.com.abc.*=DEBUG

rest-template.connection.timeout=600
rest-template.read.timeout=600

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,metrics
management.health.db.enabled=false

allowed-origin=*
spring.config.import=optional:file:.env[.properties]
server.port=${PORT:8080}
```

Here are warnings that I am able to see while building the native image in case it helps to find the issue.

```
Warning: Could not resolve org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform.
Warning: Method com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.getScheduledExecutorService() not found.
Warning: Method com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.isInitializationFailFast() not found.
Warning: Method com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.isJdbc4ConnectionTest() not found.
Warning: Method com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setInitializationFailFast(boolean) not found.
Warning: Method com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setJdbc4ConnectionTest(boolean) not found.
Warning: Method com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setScheduledExecutorService(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) not found.
Warning: Could not resolve com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.
Warning: Could not resolve groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation.
Warning: Could not resolve groovy.lang.Script for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.Script.
Warning: Could not resolve groovy.lang.Script for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.Script.
Warning: Could not resolve groovyjarjarantlr.CommonToken for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovyjarjarantlr.CommonToken.
Warning: Could not resolve javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue.
Warning: Could not resolve javax.money.MonetaryAmount for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.money.MonetaryAmount.
Warning: Could not resolve org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.GroovySourceAST for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.GroovySourceAST.
Warning: Could not resolve org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilderTransformation for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilderTransformation.
Warning: Could not resolve org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.
Warning: Could not resolve org.glassfish.expressly.ValueExpressionImpl for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.expressly.ValueExpressionImpl.
Warning: Could not resolve org.glassfish.expressly.parser.AstValue for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.expressly.parser.AstValue.
Warning: Could not resolve org.joda.time.ReadableInstant for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.ReadableInstant.
Warning: Could not register method org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.time.future.FutureValidatorForReadablePartial.<init>() for reflection. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.
Warning: Could not register method org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.time.futureorpresent.FutureOrPresentValidatorForReadablePartial.<init>() for reflection. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.
Warning: Could not register method org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.time.past.PastValidatorForReadablePartial.<init>() for reflection. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.
Warning: Could not register method org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.time.pastorpresent.PastOrPresentValidatorForReadablePartial.<init>() for reflection. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.
Warning: Could not resolve org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.
Warning: Could not resolve oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.
Warning: Could not resolve org.h2.Driver for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver.
Warning: Could not resolve org.postgresql.util.PGobject for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.util.PGobject.
```

Comment: Have you tried 3.1.1 which was released and do you have any specific configuration for Hibernate/JPA in your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @M.Deinum. I will try v3.1.1 and will share the details here. Regarding Hibernate/JPA config I do not have any specific config I have updated the question with application.properties file and few warning while I build the native image

Comment: @M.Deinum using v3.1.1 I am getting the same message with additional `jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}` I have set `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;database=db_name;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;`

Comment: If you have `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` as environment variable don't put that in as the `spring.datasource.url` it will already override that one. One thing is that youu have JPA repositories as lazy, not sure if that impacts your native image as that delays the JPA creation.

Comment: @M.Deinum If I replace `spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}` with `spring.datasource.url=` in application.properties file and set `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` as env, I am getting `Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine suitable jdbc url
`

Comment: You shouldn't specify it or provide a default. However I wonder that would even work, with Native you are quite closed world so I doubt it will look at the environment properties. While passing `--spring.datasource.url=<yuourvalue>` might still work. Also when do you get this error, while building the image or while running the image? If it is the latter you are running into limitations of native images, else you ar doing something really weird in your application.